# Results for values of the residues in the Residue Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

- If the sum of the residue is $0$, what can I conclude: that the value of the integral is $0$ or that the integral diverges?
- If the residue tends to $\infty$, should I conclude that the integral diverges?

Comment: If the sum of the residues **inside** the contour is 0, then yes, the integral is 0, given that the function $f$ and your contour satisfy the conditions of the residue theorem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the second part of your question.

Comment: Thank you for the first answer. I am having problems when I try to calculate the residue of $$f(z)=\frac{z\cdot e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{1+z}$$ for $z=0$ as the limit diverges. Should I recalculate the residue using series expansion?

Comment: Your function has an essential singularity, so yes, you do need to use the series expansion. You can alternatively find the residue at infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you REALLY want to use the Laurent series expansion, this is how it goes:

\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{1+z} (z e^{1/z}) &= (1-z+z^2-z^3+\dots)\cdot z (1+\dfrac{1}{z}+\dfrac{1}{2!z^2} + \dfrac{1}{3!z^3}+\dots)\\
& = z^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}-\dfrac{1}{5!}+\dots\right)+\text{other terms we don't care about}
\end{align}

Now, if you look at the coefficient, 
$$\left(\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}-\dfrac{1}{5!}+\dots\right)$$ is exactly

\begin{align}
e^z & = 1 + z + \dfrac{z^2}{2!} + \dfrac{z^3}{3!}+\dfrac{z^4}{4!}+\dfrac{z^5}{5!}+\dots\\
e^{-1}&=1+(-1)+\dfrac{(-1)^2}{2!} + \dfrac{(-1)^3}{3!}+\dfrac{(-1)^4}{4!}+\dfrac{(-1)^5}{5!}+\dots\\
e^{-1}&=\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}-\dfrac{1}{5!}+\dots
\end{align}

Comment: Ah! I was comparing it with the series expansion of $e^z$ for $z=0$. I don't really want to, I have to for academic purposes. 

But I can't see that $$\left(\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}-\frac{1}{5!}+\dots\right)$$

is the Taylor series expansion of $e^z$, Mathematica tells me that is
$$\frac{(z+1)^5}{5! e}+\frac{(z+1)^4}{4! e}+\frac{(z+1)^3}{3! e}+\frac{(z+1)^2}{2 e}+\frac{z+1}{e}+\frac{1}{e}$$.


Thank you very much! You are being so much helpful.

Comment: (I'm not as interested in the answer as I'm with the procedure!). That's why I am so stubborn with the series, I really want to understand every part of it.

Comment: It is the series expansion for $e^z$ **centered** at $a=0$. The $-1$ has been plugged into the series expansion.

Comment: Of course! Thank you a lot! Such an amazing help!

Comment: No problem. Glad I coud help.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This was too long to post as a comment, but it is written in response to a comment by OP.

Here is a nice way to compute the residue at 0 that avoids having to fall back to series.

$$2\pi i\, \mathrm{Res}_{z=0}(f)= \int_C \dfrac{ze^{1/z}}{1+z} dz$$

Let's just say that $C$ is the circle $C = \{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|=0.5\}$

Finding the Laurent series of this function centered at 0 can be a bit of a pain.

But what if we applied a change of variable $z = 1/w$?

\begin{align}
\int\limits_{C} \dfrac{ze^{1/z}}{1+z} dz& = \int\limits_{-\Gamma} \dfrac{e^w/w}{1+1/w} \left(-\frac{1}{w^2}\right)dw\\
& = \int\limits_{\Gamma} \dfrac{e^w/w}{1+1/w} \left(\frac{1}{w^2}\right)dw\\
& = \int\limits_{\Gamma} \dfrac{e^w}{w+1} \left(\frac{1}{w^2}\right)dw\\
\end{align}

Where $\Gamma = \{ w\in \mathbb{C}: |w|=2\}$ is a circle of radius $2$ centered at 0. It encloses two singular points, $w=0$ and $w=-1$.

$$\displaystyle\int\limits_{\Gamma} \dfrac{e^w}{w+1} \left(\frac{1}{w^2}\right)dw$$ can be computed by looking at $w=0$ (pole of order 2) and $w=-1$ (pole of order 1).

---

To calculate the residue of a pole of order $(n+1)$,

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=z_0}(f) = \dfrac{1}{n!}\dfrac{d^{n}(z-z_0)^{n+1}f}{dz^n}(z_0)$$

To calculate the residue at $w=0$ of $\dfrac{e^w}{w+1} \frac{1}{w^2}$, first note that this is a pole of order $2 = 1+1$, $n=1$. So

$$\mathrm{Res}_{w=0}(f)= \left.\dfrac{1}{1!}\dfrac{d}{dw}\dfrac{e^w}{w+1}\right|_{w=0}$$

Comment: Yes, the residue at $w=0$ is in fact zero, but that wouldn't make your integral divergent. (Divergent means that there is no finite value corresponding to the integral, and 0 is finite.) You also need to look at the residue at $w=-1$.

Comment: I made some edits to my answer. I hope it helps, and let me know if you'd like for me to expand a bit further. (Btw, the final answer is $e^{-1}$ or $2\pi i e^{-1}$, depending on whether you just want the residue or the integral.)

Comment: Ok, I thought that if one of the residues was 0 the integral was divergent. 

So, with $w=-1$ I get the residue $-1/e$ but using some known results $$Laurent[\frac{1}{z+1}]=1-z+z²-z³+z⁴...+(-1)^{n+1}\cdot{z^n}$$ and $$Laurent[e^{1/z}]=1+z^{-1}+\frac{z^{-2}}{2!}+\frac{z^{-3}}{3!}+...+\frac{z^{-n}}{n!}$$ I can see that the coeficients of the terms $z^{-1}$, the residue, is $$-\sum\frac{1}{n!}$$

Shouldn't I be getting $\sum(1+1/n)^{-n}$?

Comment: The residue should be positive 1/e.

Comment: You forgot a factor of $z$ in your expansion. You do in fact get $1/e$ is you use the series expansion.

Comment: I posted another answer that computes the residue using series.

Comment: Aix, so where am I getting it wrong? $$\frac{z\cdot e^{1/z}}{1+z}=z(1-z+z²+...)(1+z^{-1}+z^{-2}/2!+...)$$ $$=(z-z^2+z² +...)(1+z^{-1}+z^{-2}/2!+...)$$ $$=z^{-1}\cdot \sum 1/n!(-1)^{n}$$